# Brython: import the bs4 library and the requests library

Tags: python, html, brython

I am creating a web application using python with the brython.js library and for my application I need to import the bs4 library and the requests library but I don't know how.

Any idea?

```
<script type="text/python">
from browser import document
import bs4 #doesn't work
import requests #doesn't work
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import library using Brython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001634/how-to-import-library-using-brython)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in standard Python, you can install modules or packages Python in your application by putting them in the root directory, or in directories with a file `__init__.py`.

**Note:** that modules must be encoded in utf-8; the encoding declaration at the top of the script is ignored.

For instance, the application can be made of the following files and directories:

```
app.html
brython.js
brython_modules.js
brython_stdlib.js
index.html
users.py
utils.py
+ app
    __init__.py
    records.py
    tables.py
```

And you can run the imports:

```py
import users
import app.records
```

Comment: This is just a copypaste from official manual and it's very unclear https://brython.info/static_doc/en/import.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ajax`, a function in the browser module.

```py
from browser import ajax
def read(req):
    print(req.text)
ajax.get('https://example.com', oncomplete=read)
```

**Note**: You may face issues regarding CORS

Comment: CORS is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS